# Pandas,Geopandas.- Spatial join operations

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to associate to each point a number relative to the zone in which it falls. Everything works if df contains up to about 2,000,000: it takes no more than several seconds. Though, when I try to use my whole dataset, I cannot reach same goal since it seems to take hours and hours. No error seems to occur.

```
df=gpd.sjoin(df, zones, how='left', op='within')
df.drop(columns=['index_right'], inplace=True)
df['zoneId']=df['zoneId'].fillna(99).astype(int)
```

I'd like to know if `gpd.sjoin` operation cost is usually proportional to database size, and, which other kinds of mess I might be facing. Could it make sense to split df in many smaller dfs and than `concat`? I mean, there is something like chunk option (when reading a file) to be applied in order to split df not when importing it?

Comment: did you build an rtree?

Comment: isn't that built automatically in latest geopandas version ? I don't remember where I read that

Comment: How big is the whole dataset? Rtree is built automatically under the hood.

Comment: Dataset counts about 30kk rows. Though I don't want to apply spatial join on the whole dataset. So, in order to reduce computation time, I already  splitted it: df is the subset of rows on which I want to apply spatial join (1 third of total amount of rows, hence 10kk), while df2 will have '99' as fixed value on the column where zone will be insered for df. If I run the code for 3kk rows of the original dataset (spatial join on 1kk rows), it takes no more than 1 minute. 
Zones are about 30.

Comment: Are you saying that 30kk = 30,000 (typically denoted 30k)? Or are you saying 30 k x k = 30M = 30,000,000?

Comment: sorry for having been not clear at all. I mean 1kk=1,000,000